# PHP PDOStatement: get parameter bindings

Tags: php, pdo

[The documentation for debugDumpParams](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.debugdumpparams.php) says

> It will provide the SQL query in use, the number of parameters used (Params), the list of parameters, with their name, type (paramtype) as an integer, their key name or position, **the value,** and the position in the query (if this is supported by the PDO driver, otherwise, it will be -1).

However, as noted by user *thefox* on that page,

> This function **doesn't print parameter values** despite the documentation says it does. See https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=52384 (filed back in 2010).

This makes it close to useless, and the bug isn't going to be solved. So, in absence of that, **how do I get at the parameter bindings?**

Answer (score -1):

Strictly speaking, you have them already. That's binding parameters, after all, which you are passing into binding/execute. It's always a good idea to have them in array already - it makes usage neat and lets you easily debug parameters as well.